# when i convert input value into integer, valueerror pops up

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, error-handling, casting

I wrote a code for guessing numbers that are auto generated by the computer. I should get and store the user's guessing in a variable called as ans and compare it with the random number generated.

But, I cant type cast the string answer into int.

```
import random
def guess(x):
    num=random.randint(1,x)
    ans=0
    while ans!=num:
       ** ans=input("enter the guessing number")
        ans=int(ans)**
        if ans<num:
            print("number is greater")
        elif ans>num:
            print("number is lesser")
        else :
            print("correct")
```

I tried :

```
ans=input("enter guessing")
ans=ans(int)
```

yet

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: What are you typing as input?

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
ans=input("enter guessing")
ans=int(ans)
```

or you can directly cast when getting input

```
ans=int(input("enter guessing"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are receiving an empty string `''` from the user. As an empty string is not "int-like", this raises a `ValueError`. The same error would rise if you try to `int("A random string")`, and would not if you `int("350")`.

I suggest trying to handle the case where the user enters an invalid input. You could use the `isnumeric()` function to assess this, like this:

```
ans = input("enter the guessing number")

while not isnumeric(ans):
    ans = input("Error: Non-numeric value give. Enter a numeric value.")
```